# Unable to debug on Eclipse in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, ubuntu

I am able to build and run on Eclipse C/C++ installed on Ubuntu 11.10.

But on trying to debug by inserting breakpoints, I get the error shown in the link.

http://i42.tinypic.com/15plwdw.png

Does anyone know why does this occur? Can anyone resolve this?

Comment: Uhm, I vaguely recall a case where .gdbinit must be supplied with an explicit path, or maybe using the workspace variable. Can't be of more specific help, but that should put you in the right direction.

Comment: what is your build configuration and run configuration like? It's saying it can't setup the program...

Comment: Are you able to run the program in debug mode ("debug launch configuration")? Try to first have a valid debug launch configuration before you set any breakpoints or switch to the debug perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your  project name or path name any spaces? I read in the ubuntuforums something about it and I think that was the problem. I cannot find the link right now, but maybe that will work for you too!

Edit: here it is: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=43577